Classes method execution and systemverilog regions
I want to know when does any class method be executed, is it in active region set or re-active region set.
I'm Trying to understand more the time that the design receive the input values from the environment, when the driver toggles the interface signals, is this process happens in the active or re-active region, and also when the monitor samples the DUT signals is this process happens at active or re-active region.
I'm trying to understand the Scheduling semantic of system Verilog
giving this example what will be the value of b ?
module tb;
  int b;
  class cla;
    function void changeb(input int bdash);
      b = bdash;
    endfunction
  endclass
  cla clainst = new();
  initial begin
    clainst.changeb(23); // Executes in the Active region or Re-active region
    $display("b=%0d", b); // Prints b=23 or b = 0   
  end
endmodule


hello, it prints b=23

Class methods or any other task/function for that matter are not tied to any specific scheduling regions. Procedural processes are started by initial, always, continuous assignments, or assertion action blocks. Once started, calling a method does not change the region the process executes in. One caveat is you can suspend a process waiting for a signal to change, and that change may happen in a different region, but the process resumes in the same region it original started in.
In your example, your process gets started by an initial block in a module, so the assignment to b executes and gets updated in the active region. The $display statement that follows it prints its new value 23. Had you used a nonblocking assignment to b, it would still have its old value 0 when printed.

Thank you Dave!                                                                                                                                   I have another question, what if i was
#0 clainst.changeb(23);
$display("b=%0d", b);                                                                                                                    i thought it would be b=0 since $display is active region event and #0 in-active region event but the value was 23 why?

Is it because the simulator execute each sentence with the same order it was appeared and each sentence is adjust a delta cycle so line 1 means delta 1 and line 2 means delta 2 ...etc. and since #0 means add delta cycle  so all the sentences after it will be shifted by one delta, right?

I'm confused because of the requirement which states that we can't go from a region to the next region before finishing all the scheduled  events at this region within the same time slot, so i thought we will schedule #0 clainst.changeb(23); and put it in the in-active region events queue but it will not be executed before we finish the active region events queue so i thought $display would be executed first and then b will be updated but i think i didn't understand this part well

Blocking assignments require the update happens before the next statement executes.
